Setting Log Verbosity for a ComposableNode
I have a launch file that is creating a ComposableNode and conditionally adding it to a pre-existing container if the name of the container is passed as an argument.  If no container is specified then a new container is created at launch and the component is loaded.
I would like to be able to set the verbosity level of the component prior to it being added to any container.  Here is the key part of the launch file:
def generate_launch_description():

  package_name = 'my_package'
  node_name = LaunchConfiguration('__node')
  namespace = LaunchConfiguration('__ns')
  log_level = LaunchConfiguration('__log_level')
  target_container = LaunchConfiguration('target_container')

  share_dir = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
  launch_dir = os.path.join(share_dir, 'launch')

  declare_ns = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    '__ns',
    default_value=package_name,
    description='Namespace for container and all nodes contained therein',
  )

  declare_nn = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    '__node',
    default_value='some_name',
    description='Remap the node name',
  )

  declare_log_level = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    '__log_level', default_value='info', description='Set log level'
  )

  declare_use_sim_time = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'use_sim_time',
    default_value='False',
    description='Use sim time',
  )

  declare_container = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='target_container', default_value='',
    description=(
      'Name of an existing node container in which to load components. '
      'If unset, a new container will be created.'
    )
  )
  composable_nodes = [
    ComposableNode(
      name=node_name,
      namespace=namespace,
      package=package_name,
      plugin='my_plugin::plugin',
      extra_arguments=[{'LOG_LEVEL':'DEBUG'}]  # <- I'd like to do something like this
    )
  ]  

  return LaunchDescription(
    [
      declare_ns,
      declare_nn,
      declare_log_level,
      declare_use_sim_time,
      declare_container,

      ComposableNodeContainer(
        condition=LaunchConfigurationEquals('target_container', ''),
        package='rclcpp_components',
        executable='component_container',
        name=package_name+'_container',
        namespace='',
        arguments=['--ros-args', '--log-level', log_level], # <- I don't want to do this
        composable_node_descriptions=composable_nodes
      ),

      LoadComposableNodes(
        condition=LaunchConfigurationNotEquals('target_container', ''),
        composable_node_descriptions=composable_nodes,
        target_container=target_container
      )
    ]
  )

I've tried a variety of things to get this to work, but I can only get the debug output when I pass in the log level as an argument to the container or when I manually set the logger verbosity in the cpp file manually. Any suggestions on what I could try?
Thanks in advance!
